# Simscape, COMSOL compatibility in simulating electromagnetic range of inductive charging

Tags: matlab, simscape, ansys, comsol

I am currently trying to use Simscape to design and simulate the electrical circuit and COMSOL Multiphysics to simulate the electromagnetic interaction between coils. What I'm not certain of is whether or not we can successfully link the two software packages nicely via MATLAB or not. They both have MATLAB support though.
I am also researching whether ANSYS suite. There may be some software we can use that would take the place of one or both of the previous software.

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I had to make a connection between COMSOL and Matlab as well. This is called a Matlab Comsol **LiveLink**.

However, I think (not sure), that the electrical circuit should be modeled in COMSOL. Using the LiveLink you can set parameters in COMSOL using Matlab and extract the updated calculation. To my knowledge you cannot input a model, do calculations, and then extract the results.

You can look in the [users guide](http://www.lmn.pub.ro/%7Edaniel/ElectromagneticModelingDoctoral/Books/COMSOL4.3/llmatlab/LiveLinkForMATLABUsersGuide.pdf), maybe it says something about this

Some other links which may be useful:

- [LiveLink™ for MATLAB®](https://www.comsol.com/release/5.3a/livelink-matlab)
- [Integrate COMSOL Multiphysics® with
  MATLAB® Scripting](https://www.comsol.com/livelink-for-matlab)